# Red/Green test colors when using KIF for iPhone

Tags: ios, tdd, bdd, kif-framework

Is there a way to add Red Green colors to the console for passing and failing tests on the KIF framework? I'm not sure if this is in the works or if it's possible. Maybe by running the tests from the console?